# Array in value of hash

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

How to push inputs into a value of a hash? My problem is that I got multiple keys and all of them reference arrays.

```
{"A"=>["C"], "B"=>["E"], "C"=>["D"], "D"=>["B"]}
```

How can I push another String onto one of these? For example I want to add a `"Z"` to the array of key `"A"`?

Currently I either overwrite the former array or all data is in one.

Its about converting a Array `["AB3", "DC2", "FG4", "AC1", "AF4"]` into a hash with `{"A"=>["B", "C", "F"]}`.

Answer (score 1):

Any command `<<, push, unshift` will do a job

```
if h["A"] 
  h["A"] << "Z"
else
  h["A"] = ["Z"]
end
```

Comment: It doesnt work this way. The problem is there is no array to push in currently "undefined method "<<"  for nil:NilClass"

my Code

`for counter in 0..($graph.size)-1 do
    #Key wird erstellt
    temp_start = $graph[counter][0, 1]
    temp_finish = $graph[counter][1, 1]

    puts temp_start
    puts temp_finish
    $routen[temp_start] << temp_finish

    end
  end`

Comment: then just check for existence of value

Comment: Thank u  very much! Im completely new to programming and ruby, so i didnt come to this easy solution :)

Comment: @user1446375 to avoid the _undefined method "<<" for nil_ error you could [create the hash with a block](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-c-new): `Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }`. That way the block supplies default values for the hash.

Answer (score 0):

You said your original problem is converting the array `["AB3", "DC2", "FG4", "AC1", "AF4"]` into the hash `{"A"=>["B", "C", "F"]}`, which can be done like this:

```
Hash[a.group_by { |s| s[0] }.map { |k, v| [k, v.map { |s| s[1] }] }]
```

Or like this:

```
a.inject(Hash.new{|h, k| h[k]=[]}) { |h, s| h[s[0]] << s[1] ; h }
```

Note that `Hash.new{|h, k| h[k]=[]}` creates an array with a default value of `[]` (an empty array), so you'll always be able to use `<<` to add elements to it.

Answer (score 0):

Better approach:

Add a new class method in Hash as below:

```
class Hash
  def add (k,v)
    unless self.key?k
      self[k] = [v] 
    else
      self[k] = self[k] << v
    end 
    self
  end 
end


h={}
h.add('A','B') #=> {"A"=>["B"]}
h.add('A','C') #=> {"A"=>["B", "C"]}
h.add('B','X') #=> {"A"=>["B", "C"], "B"=>["X"]}
```

Done.

This can be even more idiomatic according to your precise problem; say, you want to send multiple values at once, then code can be DRY-ed to handle multiple arguments.

Hope this helps.

All the best.